# Firefox closes everytime I use the quick search to search

Tags: ubuntu, firefox

I recently installed Firefox on Ubuntu 9.10, but now everytime I try to search using the Quick Search Firefox closes without any warning.

It's Firefox 3.5.7

Comment: run firefox from terminal & paste the output..

Comment: I uninstalled YSlow extension and then it worked

Comment: just curious, what error was shown on terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled YSlow Extension and Firefox was fine again

Comment: what made you try this?

Comment: When I installed Firefox, I went on to install all my extensions that I use, so I just decide to uninstall them one by one, and it worked when I uninstalled YSlow

Comment: YSlow had a few upgrades recently and one of those was buggy. Upgrade past the affected release.